# Spring Hibernate Cannot add foreign key constraint on initializing database

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, kotlin, mariadb

When Spring is initializing, I get the following exception: 
https://pastebin.com/abMuS4v3

Here is the kotlin code where the exception happened, it's part of the constructor of an entity:

```
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(joinColumns = [(JoinColumn(name = "id"))])
    @Column(name = "authenticated_factor")
    val authenticatedFactors: MutableSet<CredentialType> = hashSetOf(),
```

CredentialType is a enum class.

**Interestingly this exception happens on MySQL but not on MariaDB.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the ddl-auto mode of your application?

Comment: @Piwo it's update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with some research, I arrived at somewhat of a solution. (It's really a workaround)

If you use ddl-auto mode `create` , `none` , `validate` or `create-drop` it would actually work. I know it has a different effect. But anyways it works for now. I think this has something to do with how MySQL is dealing with updating constrains.

BTW: It still happen with the MySQL57Dialect selected in the configuration file.

Comment: Okay, this is actually an issue with the Mysql driver. Select the the proper driver package would be a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by switching hibernate dialect from MySQL5Dialect to MySQL5InnoDBDialect.
Hope it helps.